# Change title of page using JQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Can I change the title of my page through any tag in the body of the page through jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: What is the master-child page concept? And what can't you use?

Comment: i have a master page with the header and footer intact but the content of it changes just by calling the div ids which is in another file.............itls like placeholders in asp.net

Answer (score 1):

Where you load the page, you probably have a "page load success" function somewhere.

There just add

```
document.title = $('#elementId').text();
```

as suggested.

So if you are using JQuery load() function:

```
$("#content").load( url,data, successFunction);

function successFunction(someResponseText, someTextStatus, anXMLHttpRequest) {
    document.title = $('#elementId').text();
    ...
}
```

provided your loaded sub page has `<div id="elementId">My Great Title</div>` in it.

Comment: i have a span tag ........will it work?

Comment: Yes, as long ast it has a correct id. `<span id="elementId">My Great Title</span>`

Comment: @SuperSonic The important thing is that you must do this after the subpage has loaded, so the success function is a good place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.title = $('#elementId').text();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you feel like doing it in javascript, this is a way to do it.

first, in your html, you should have a tag that can call your function, in this example, the body tag has an onload function

```
<body onload="titleChange()">
```

Here is the javascript;

```
function titleChange(){
    document.title = "Your new title.";
}
```